# MySQL query to insert data only when two fields are not exist

Tags: jquery, mysql, insert

I have a students table, I would like to insert data if the email and phone number is not exist in the table. I tried this query,

```
INSERT INTO studesnts (name, phone, email, address) 
  VALUES ('vinod','9999999999','xyz@example.com','my address') 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studesnts WHERE phone ='9999999999' AND email='xyz@example.com')
```

But this query returns an error,

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studesnts ( WHERE phone ='9999999999' ' at line 2
```

How do fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VALUES` does not take a `WHERE` clause.  You can use `SELECT` instead:

```
INSERT INTO students (name, phone, email, address) 
    SELECT s.*
    FROM (SELECT 'vinod' as name, '9999999999' as phone, 'xyz@example.com' as email, 'my address' as address) s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM students s2
                      WHERE s2.phone = s.phone AND s2.email = s.email
                     );
```

However, you probably intend avoiding students that have the same phone and email in the table.  If so, create a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_students_phone_email on students(phone, email);
```

That way, the database guarantees the integrity of the data.  Under normal circumstances that will result in an error.  If you just want the duplicate insert to be ignored, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO students (name, phone, email, address) 
    VALUES ('vinod', '9999999999', 'xyz@example.com', 'my address') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE phone = VALUES(phone);
```

This does a no-op in the case of duplicates.